# How to use advance Ansible playbook conditionals to parse json?

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I'm attempting to create a playbook that uses the uri module for creating new watcher tasks in ElasticSearch. However I seem to be getting something wrong with the conditional for checking the register payload as I keep running into the an error; "error while evaluating conditional: payload.contents.find("true") != -1"

What is the correct way to evaluate the returned json from the uri module?

[Related files on gist](https://gist.github.com/denzuko/9a39094b7ad0fcfd02b2)

(btw, I'm running this playbook via vagrant doing provisioning so debugging by dumping the variable playbook is next to impossible and the playbook dies before registering anyways.)

Comment: Have you tried using the `debug` module to see the content of your `payload` variable? Also please post relevant part of your code directly in the question. If that gist ever disappears, this question will be useless w/o that context.

Comment: @Mxx Yes! and the playbook drops before getting to that ruleset. (btw, I never delete gists but could post the code here in the question if need be. Just didn't post them here so the question would not get flagged for review)

Comment: Further Digging would show that cluster_health_watch_body is being passed as a dictionary to the body parameter of the `uri()` module. However adding the jinja filter `to_json` just completely breaks the playbook. Any help at this point to figure out what's the cause of this would be welcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like since I'm using the [EPEL build](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/a/ansible-1.9.2-1.el7.noarch.rpm), the issue was related to [Ansible Pull Request #1011](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/pull/1011) in that the body_type set to json was not correctly identifying the variable as a string value since the body was being passed to uri as a dictionary instead.

The fix for this was to use lookup('template', '...') instead of a variable

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

`changed_when: (payload.content | from_json).created | bool`

Comment: @Matt_Davis I see the logic in your answer however two things comes up; 1) this did not work as I got an unexpected type error that failed because ansible/jinja was expected string or buffertype. 2) Which also goes into the test is for a value returned for created that is "True" ie var created = String("True") the boolean true/false. Weither the two are related is beyond me at this point. Why would the template fail?

Comment: Not having access to your actual URL endpoint to test against, I'm not sure why it would fail... I'd suggest commenting out your changed_when and playing around with building up the template expression in a subsequent debug statement to try and figure out what's wrong. The reason for the | bool at the end was to account for the fact that the contents of "created" could be a quoted string "true/false" instead of naked bool.

Comment: Comes down to the compiled template is being passed as a python dictionary instead of a string to uri(body). It still posts the template but after that it doesn't parse any return json.

Comment: Yeah, that'd do it... The to_json seems extraneous/wrong, since the output of the template should already be stringified JSON (to_json is for converting dicts to json strings).